# Changing the outlier rule in a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have constructed some box-plots in R and have several outliers. I know that the default criteria to set outlier limits are:

- Q3 + 1.5*IQR
- Q1 - 1.5* IQR

However, I would like outliers classified as values that fall outside of the boundaries:

- Q3 + 3*IQR
- Q1 - 3* IQR

Is it possible to set this in R?

Comment: This recent questions also seems relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946964/in-ggplot2-what-do-the-end-of-the-boxplot-lines-represent

Answer (score 25):

From `?boxplot`

> **range**: this determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the box.  If ‘range’ is positive, the whiskers extend to the most extreme data point which is no more than ‘range’ times the interquartile range from the box. A value of zero causes the whiskers to extend to the data extremes.

So set `range=3`

Answer (score 20):

I'd encourage you not to do this without a lot of thought - people expect that the whiskers extend 1.5 IQRs. Changing the range will violate these assumptions and make it easy for people to draw incorrect conclusions from your graphic.

Comment: I agree that Tukey's box-plots are extremely useful for visualizing outliers. However, in some cases, it is useful to use "5-points plots" to compare the distribution on the data within different samples from min to max, without the distraction of the outliers  This should be explained in the text.

Answer (score 0):

In python,
whis :Paramater that controls whisker length. If scalar, whiskers are drawn to the farthest datapoint within whis * IQR from the nearest hinge. If a tuple, it is interpreted as percentiles that whiskers represent

---

import seaborn as sns

sns.boxplot(x=feature, hue="label", data=df ,whis=3)

Comment: Hello Ilknur, this is a topic related to `R` programming