# Combining medcouple in ggplot's boxplot

Tags: r, robust, ggplot2

ggplot's boxplot render any dot outside the range [Q1 - 1.5 * IQR, Q3 + 1.5 * IQR] as an outlier. As discussed in the [R blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-outliers-in-numerical-data/), this is not always a good idea, as 
false outliers may be reported due to asymmetric distributions. In that case, adjbox, from the robustbase R package, is often suggested. However, the quality
of the plot is not as good as ggplot2.

My question is: does anybody know how to combine the exponential model used
in adjbox to be used by ggplot when detecting outliers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to have to supply the values yourself. Referencing the example used in the `adjbox()` help file:

```
library(robustbase)
if(require("boot")) {
  ### Hubert and Vandervieren (2006), p. 10, Fig. 4.
  data(coal, package = "boot")
  coaldiff <- diff(coal$date)
  op <- par(mfrow = c(1,2))
  boxplot(coaldiff, main = "Original Boxplot")
  adjbox(coaldiff, main  = "Adjusted Boxplot")
  par(op)
}
```

This produces the following boxplots:

[image]

Then you can get the values that the `adjbox()` function used:

```
coald <- data.frame(coaldiff = diff(coal$date))  #$
adjboxStats(coald$coaldiff)$stats
# [1] 0.0000000 0.1013005 0.3107461 0.7529090 3.7180014
```

These are the values used to draw the adjusted boxplot. You can use supply this information to `ggplot()` and then calculate your own boxplots. There are probably better ways of doing this, but the first thing that I thought of doing was to make a new data set including the adjusted boxplot values:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
d <- ddply(coald, .(coaldiff), transform,
  ymin = adjboxStats(coald$coaldiff)$stats[1],
  ymax = adjboxStats(coald$coaldiff)$stats[5],
  middle = adjboxStats(coald$coaldiff)$stats[3],
  lower = adjboxStats(coald$coaldiff)$stats[2],
  upper = adjboxStats(coald$coaldiff)$stats[4])

# Boxplot with unadjusted values:
p <- ggplot(d, aes(factor(1), coaldiff)) 
p + geom_boxplot()

# Boxplot with adjusted values (note that you have to add the outliers back in):
p + geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, middle=middle, upper=upper, lower=lower),
  stat="identity") + 
  geom_point(data=subset(d, coaldiff < ymin | coaldiff > ymax))
```

This will give you `ggplot2` versions of the above plots:

[image]

Also note that Hadley Wickham advises against this "without a lot of thought" in a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5005213/1088647) to a similar question.