# Method of Outlier Removal for Boxplots

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

In R, what method is used in [boxplot()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html) to remove outliers? In other words, what determines if a given value is an outlier?

Please note, this question is **not** asking *how* to remove outliers.

**EDIT**: Why is this question being downvoted? Please provide comments. The method for outlier removal is not available in any documentation I have come across.

Comment: I can only imagine why the down-votes, but I think some people might not consider this a programming question in the narrowest sense.

Comment: See this [Changing the outlier rule in a boxplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994313/changing-the-outlier-rule-in-a-boxplot)

Comment: @d.b - Thanks. I know how to calculate an outlier. Is this the method that R's `boxplot()` uses?

Comment: BTW, you can check the code in `?boxplot.default`.

Comment: almost (but not *quite*?) a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946964/in-ggplot2-what-do-the-end-of-the-boxplot-lines-represent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** outliers are points that are beyond *approximately* twice the interquartile range away from the median (in a symmetric case). More precisely, points beyond a cutoff equal to the 'hinges' (approx. 1st and 3d quartiles) +/- 1.5 times the interquartile range.

R's `boxplot()` function does not actually *remove* outliers at all; all observations in the data set are represented in the plot (unless the `outline` argument is `FALSE`). The information on the calculation for which points are plotted as outliers (i.e., as individual points beyond the whiskers) is, implicitly, contained in the description of the `range` parameter:

> range [default 1.5]: this determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the
>             box.  If ‘range’ is positive, the whiskers extend to the most
>             extreme data point which is no more than ‘range’ times the
>             interquartile range from the box. A value of zero causes the
>             whiskers to extend to the data extremes.

This has to be deconstructed a little bit more: what does "from the box" mean? To figure this out, we need to look at the *Details* of `?boxplot.stats`:

> The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile,
>        i.e., close to ‘quantile(x, c(1,3)/4)' [... see `?boxplot.stats` for slightly more detail ...]

The reason for all the complexity/"approximately equal to the quartile" language is that the developers of the boxplot wanted to make sure that the hinges and whiskers were always drawn at points representing actual observations in the data set (whereas the quartiles can be located between observed points, e.g. in the case of data sets with odd numbers of observations).

Example:

```
set.seed(101)
z <- rnorm(100000)
boxplot(z)
hinges <- qnorm(c(0.25,0.75)) 
IQR <- diff(qnorm(c(0.25,0.75)))
abline(h=hinges,lty=2,col=4) ## hinges ~ quartiles
abline(h=hinges+c(-1,1)*1.5*IQR,col=2)
## in this case hinges = +/- IQR/2, so whiskers ~ +/- 2*IQR
abline(h=c(-1,1)*IQR*2,lty=2,col="purple")
```

[image]