# geom_boxplot: change outlier rules

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

how do I change outlier rules in geom_boxplot? In boxplot, I just need to set range = 3. Also, how do I set lower and upper?

```
individual_SoA_plots <- lapply(individual_SoA_data,
                              function(x) {
                                ggplot(x, aes(x = x$GROUP, y =x$AgingOfAlert)) +
                                  geom_boxplot(ymin = 0, ymax = 162,
                                               col=" dark blue", fill = "green",
                                               outlier.colour = "#1F3552", outlier.shape = 20) +
                                  scale_y_continuous(name = "Aging Of Alerts") +
                                  scale_x_discrete(name = "Current State", limits = GROUPtype) +
                                  ggtitle(x$SourceOfAlert[1]) + theme_bw() +
                                  theme(text = element_text(size=10))
                              })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the outlier rule in a boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994313/changing-the-outlier-rule-in-a-boxplot)

Comment: No, it is not, I am asking geom_boxplot, which does not have "range"

Answer (score 4):

Look into the `coef` argument for `geom_boxplot()`. It defaults to 1.5 and sets the length of whiskers based on `coef` and the inter-quartile range, with all points outside whiskers considered outliers.