# Boxplot in R uper/lower whiskers

Tags: r

I am using the most basic function of Boxplot, boxplot(x, ..., range = 1.5, but if I don't set the rang, and let R use its default value. Something like boxplot(x, ...,) what exactly quantile of the whiskers ? Because I have outliners that is larger or smaller than the upper/lower whiskers. How can I know the exact percentage of the outliners above or below the uper/lower whiskers? In other words, without setting the range, may I know what the percentage of the data is for the uper/lower whiskers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ggplot2, what do the end of the boxplot lines represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946964/in-ggplot2-what-do-the-end-of-the-boxplot-lines-represent)

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could calculate the percentage of utliers as follows:

```
# Some data with outliers:
d <- rnorm(100)
d[sample(1:100, 10)] <- rnorm(10,mean = 0, sd = 10)
bp <- boxplot(d)

# Get the values of the outliers:
out <- bp$out

# The proportion of outliers:
length(out)/length(d)*100
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is, but: `?boxplot` says the default value of `range` is 1.5, and then it says

> range: this determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the
>             box.  If ‘range’ is positive, the whiskers extend to the most
>             extreme data point which is no more than ‘range’ times the
>             interquartile range from the box. A value of zero causes the
>             whiskers to extend to the data extremes.

In other words, the whiskers are not defined as a proportion of the data, but as a multiple of the interquartile range.

If you want to know the proportions, you can use `boxplot.stats`:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- runif(100)
bb <- boxplot.stats(x)
 c(mean(x<min(bb$stats)),mean(x>max(bb$stats)))
## [1] 0 0
```

`mean(<logical value>)` is a shortcut for computing a proportion.  Because I have chosen the data from a uniform distribution, there are actually *no* points beyond the whiskers (confirmed by looking at `boxplot(x)`).  If I were to do re-do this with `rcauchy()` there would be lots ...