# R Boxplot - specify upper and lower whisker?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The lower whisker is defined by *Q1 - c * IQR*
and the upper whicker by  *Q3 + c * IQR*

being Q1 - first quartile, Q3 - third quartile, IQR - inter quartile range, and *C* a variable. Usually C is 1.5, and I'm not sure, but probably is default for boxplot().

Is it possible to specify this C value when creating a boxplot?

Solutions using ggplot2 are welcome too.

Comment: You have not told us what the data is, but are negative values possible or do they represent some kind of coding for missing data?

Comment: I would recommend this post for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787332/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-dataset. I am also pretty sure you should take @dcarlson 's suggestion seriously.

Comment: @dcarlson I am sorry you are right. After reviewing my question, i think that the context i gave isn't really needed for the problem, and it was misleading, so i decided to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Completely missed it reading the documentation, sorry.

It can be given as an argument in [`boxplot()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/boxplot):

> `range`
>
> This determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the box. If `range` is positive, the whiskers extend to the most extreme data point which is no more than `range` times the interquartile range from the box. A value of zero causes the whiskers to extend to the data extremes.

```
boxplot(x,...,range=2)
```

**Edit:** as tjebo suggested, this post ([In ggplot2, what do the end of the boxplot lines represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946964/in-ggplot2-what-do-the-end-of-the-boxplot-lines-represent)) completes the answer. Altough the title has ggplot2, it mentions the solution to my problem and might be worth checking out.

Comment: Ze, thanks for sharing, and good job answering your own question. +1 Although this was a duplicate question (see my flag) - please don't delete it. It will be useful for others for their future searches.

Comment: @tjebo Thank you for your suggestion! Altough the title meantions ggplot2, it uses the boxplot() function and has an explanation of the outlier-whisker relation and what defines a whisker too. Ill had add the link to my answer so people can check it out