# Automatically Adjust Vertical Position of Dodged Geom_text on Box-and-Whisker ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I'm trying to automatically set the height of each of the percentage labels (which correspond the the mean)to the end of the top of each whisker (for example). Is this possible with a simple function or parameter in geom_text or elsewhere? Or, would I have to go in manually and create a geom_text for each label to set its position manually?

As you can see, the current output shows that I `position_jitterdodge()`'d the percentage labels, which looks chaotic and some overlap with each other, which I'd like to avoid. Alternatively, it would be nice to be able to display the percentages within each box itself.

**ggplot Code:**

```r
ggplot(bcfourgroupbxplt, aes(x = Clusters, y = Proportions, 
                             fill = FourGroup)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = FourGroup, alpha = 0.5),
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0, 
                                             jitter.height = 0))  +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = FourGroup)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Group",
                    values = c("#20b0a8", "#f98110", "#FFC300", "#C70039"),
                    labels = c("Control", "B", "b.1", "b.2")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Control" = "#20b0a8", "B" = "#f98110", 
  "b.1" = "#FFC300", "b.2" = "#C70039"),
                     labels = c("Control", "B", "b.1", "b.2")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Mean, y = 0.9), 
            stat = "identity",
            position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0, 
                                            jitter.height = 0.15),
            size=2.5,
            data = bcmeanbxplt) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, aes(alpha = 0.5), color = "black", shape = 3, 
               position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0, 
                                               jitter.height = 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = levels(finalnewbcell$Annots)) +
  xlab("Clusters") +
  ggtitle("B cell Compartment Proportions") +
  theme_clean() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  guides(alpha = "none", color = "none")
```

**Example structure of bcfourgroupbxplt:**

## A tibble: 540 × 6

Samples Clusters       Proportions Group   Subtype FourGroup
                          
1 Ctrl1   Intermediate B      0.0556 Control Control Control
2 pt001   Intermediate B      0.103  ......B ....b.1 ....b.1
3 pt032   Intermediate B      0.192  ......B ....b.2 ....b.2
4 Ctrl37  Intermediate B      0.207  Control Control Control
25 pt032  Intermediate B      0.228  ......B ....b.2 ......B

--> the B group individuals repeat as I wanted to show the total B group as a box then split it by subgroup (b.1 and b.2)

**Code for geom_text mean:**

```r
bcmeanbxplt <- bcfourgroupbxplt %>%
  group_by(Clusters, FourGroup) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Proportions)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Mean = percent(round(Mean, 3)))
```

[image: Current Output]

I've tried changing the position to `position_dodge`, or `position_dodgev` or `position_jitterdodge`, or `position_nudge` and playing around with those arguments to no avail (possibly because I'm using `bcmeanbxplt` as the data in the `geom_text()` layer?).

**EDIT: Updated figure using solution by M.Viking**
[Updated figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK5t8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `stat_summary()` function and a helper function which returns the y location as used by the box plot geom via `boxplot.stats()`

```
boxplot.stats(iris$Petal.Width)
#$stats
#[1] 0.1 0.3 1.3 1.8 2.5   # <- the 5th value is the end of the whisker
#$n
#[1] 150
#$conf
#[1] 1.10649 1.49351

mean_text_fun <- function(x){return(data.frame(y = boxplot.stats(x)$stats[5]+0.1, 
                                               label = paste0(mean(x))))}
```

The first part of your plot code, with the `iris` dataset combined with stat_summary

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species),alpha = 0.5,
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0, jitter.height = 0))  +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_text_fun, geom = "text")
```

[image]

Stat Summary Idea - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720769/10276092

Box Plot Stats Idea - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947033/10276092